# Stack Overflow on MouseMove

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, stack-overflow

I have a picturebox bigger than the form, the form have AutoScroll set to on

So to scroll the picturebox without using the scrollbars i added this code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove


    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then

        Dim DeltaX As Integer = (m_PanStartPoint.X - e.X)
        Dim DeltaY As Integer = (m_PanStartPoint.Y - e.Y)

        Me.AutoScrollPosition = _
        New Drawing.Point((DeltaX - Me.AutoScrollPosition.X), _
                        (DeltaY - Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y))
    End If
```

It works correctly if i drag and drop the picturebox for like 2 seconds, but if i hold the middle mouse button for like 5 seconds it will give me a stack overflow exeption even that its not even a loop

Is there a way to 'fix' that stack overflow? Im not sure what a Stack Overflow exactly is so im confuse about what to do.

- mouse down event

  ```
  Private Sub PictureBox1_Mousedown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

  m_PanStartPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
  ```

Comment: A stack overflow refers the the execution stack; essentially the function calls somewhere down the line are going too deep and you're running out of space.

Comment: show the mousedown event, please

Comment: which line exactly is the exception happening on?  alone, the code posted shouldnt result in a SO.  You have code elsewhere causing it.  Do you have similar AutoScroll manipulations in Form events?

Comment: Setting the `AutoScrollPosition` property in the `MouseMove` could trigger another `MouseMove` event, which could quickly overflow the stack.

Comment: next time it crashes, open the Call Stack window and see where the code has been to figure out the source.

Comment: the stack overflow happens at: `Me.AutoScrollPosition = _
            New Drawing.Point((DeltaX - Me.AutoScrollPosition.X), _
                            (DeltaY - Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y))` @Plutonix

Comment: the code posted works fine (tested; cannot reproduce). Is there a timer involved in this?   Examine the call stack to see how the code is getting there repeatedly

Comment: @Plutonix seens that a `Application.doEvents()` much latter on the code was causing it, fixed, thanks (this question wont have an answer, should i delete it?)

Comment: never, ever use `Application.DoEvents`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/1070452   also http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/